# Is it possible to delete all databases that were created by a specific user?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to delete all databases that were created by a specific user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at MySQL's [DELETE DATABASE syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/drop-database.html), it seems impossible via MySQL itself. However, you could use 3rd party application that queries:

```
SELECT db FROM mysql.db WHERE user = "<user>"
```

to get a list of user's databases, then loop over the result to query delete database above.